# I encountered an error with the React project, and I can't get it to run

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TwM3E.png)

Hello World!
I'm having trouble running the command "npm run start" and I was hoping for your help.
Thank you!

I thought this might be a problem with the Node.js version, but I still have the same issue.

Comment: This error comes from when you executed "yarn start".

Comment: Yes, I tried both 'npm run start' and 'yarn start', but neither of them worked.

Comment: Yes, definitely, the error is due to the version of Node.

Comment: Do you have nvm installed? If not, I suggest using it to manage your node version.

Comment: If needed, I can install nvm.

Comment: I've just installed.

Comment: It works. you are very kind and smart.

Comment: [Please post code/errors/etc as formatted text instead of links to images of formatted text.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please follow these steps:

1. Install NVM
2. Install each node version within the range of 12 to 18 (7 versions).

You can view the versions of Node that you have installed using `nvm list`.

```
nvm install <node-version>
```

e.g `nvm install 18.14.0`

```
nvm use <node-version>
```

e.g `nvm use 14.16.0`

Then please run your project on different versions of Node.
Whenever you use different version, please delete `node_modules` folder and then install again.